# What if we red shift a photon of the lowest possible frequency?

Tags: photons, redshift

Properties of photons are quantised right? So what if we red shift the photons with the lowest possible frequency?

Comment: There have been empirically found photons with wavelengths of millions of lightyears. The photon you mean might never be noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frequency is continuous valued. Just like real numbers. Except frequency has a lower bound of zero. So there is no **lowest frequency**. It’s equivalent to asking what’s the smallest non-zero real number.